# Greek letter with two dots over in text mode

Tags: amsmath, greek, text, text-mode

I want to write the Greek letter theta with two dots over it in text mode, but I haven't gotten it to work yet.

I have both these packages:

```
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{textgreek}
```

and I have used `\straighttheta` when writing theta without two dots.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome. You can use `\usepackage{upgreek}` for straight theta and for two dots above `\ddot`. So the final comand should be `$\ddot \uptheta$`. Unfortunately, you need the matmoade  `$$` for the dots

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `alphabeta`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alphabeta}

\begin{document}

\accdialytika{\texttheta}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For my humble opinion great answer...I not know of alphabeta package.

Comment: I have read the documentation here: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/language/greek/greek-fontenc/alphabeta-doc.pdf. But where is it written `\accdialytika{\texttheta}` to have two dots? Thank you very much.

Comment: In that PDF it's (vaguely) documented in §4.2: "Accent macros are set up for use with the generic macros by definition of "TextComposite" commands." The actual lists of commands for applying diacritics are elsewhere in the documentation, in various HTML files: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/language/greek/greek-fontenc/

Answer (score 2):

Here there is an old answer [Adding a dot over greek letter in text mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349300/adding-a-dot-over-greek-letter-in-text-mode)  of @Steven B. Segletes that I have slightly changed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{textgreek,stackengine}
\newcommand\textdot[1]{\stackon[1pt]{\csname text#1\endcsname}{.}}
\newcommand\textdots[1]{\stackon[1pt]{\csname text#1\endcsname}{..}}
\begin{document}
\textdot{theta} and \textdots{theta}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The dots can be in the font itself, too.

More than a hundred diacritical marks, able to combine automatically with the preceding character, are available when using a suitable Unicode True Type/Open Type font, including the double dot `U+0308 COMBINING DIAERESIS` (e.g., here on an `o`: ö ). As much as the font renderer, like a browser window, can handle it, they stack, too: i̧̤̥̦̪̫̅̆̇̈̉.

Requires `fontspec` or `unicode-math` package, and compilation with xelatex or lualatex.

[image: combining diacritical marks]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.3cm} \setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}





%vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
\newfontfamily\cdmfont{Noto Serif}
\newcommand\cdmformat{\cdmfont}
\newcommand\cdmtag{{\tiny [Combining\ Diacritical\ Marks]\par}}
\newcommand\eolist{{\tiny [End of List]}\par}

%-----   Shortcut commands
\newcommand\cdmgrave{^^^^0300}
\newcommand\cdmacute{^^^^0301}
\newcommand\cdmcircum{^^^^0302}
\newcommand\cdmtilde{^^^^0303}
\newcommand\cdmmacron{^^^^0304}
\newcommand\cdmoverl{^^^^0305}
\newcommand\cdmbreve{^^^^0306}
\newcommand\cdmdot{^^^^0307}
\newcommand\cdmdiaeresis{^^^^0308}
\newcommand\cdmhook{^^^^0309}
\newcommand\cdmring{^^^^030a}
\newcommand\cdmdacute{^^^^030b}
\newcommand\cdmcaron{^^^^030c}
\newcommand\cdmvl{^^^^030d}
\newcommand\cdmdvl{^^^^030e}
\newcommand\cdmdgrave{^^^^030f}
\newcommand\cdmcrabindu{^^^^0310}
\newcommand\cdminvbreve{^^^^0311}
\newcommand\cdmtcomma{^^^^0312}
\newcommand\cdmcomma{^^^^0313}
\newcommand\cdmrevcomma{^^^^0314}
\newcommand\cdmcommaright{^^^^0315}
\newcommand\cdmgraveb{^^^^0316}
\newcommand\cdmacuteb{^^^^0317}
\newcommand\cdmlefttackb{^^^^0318}
\newcommand\cdmrighttackb{^^^^0319}
\newcommand\cdmleftangle{^^^^031a}
\newcommand\cdmhorn{^^^^031b}
\newcommand\cdmlefthalfringb{^^^^031c}
\newcommand\cdmuptackb{^^^^031d}
\newcommand\cdmdowntackb{^^^^031e}
\newcommand\cdmplussignb{^^^^031f}
\newcommand\cdmminussignb{^^^^0320}
\newcommand\cdmpalatalizedhookb{^^^^0321}
\newcommand\cdmretroflexhookb{^^^^0322}
\newcommand\cdmdotb{^^^^0323}
\newcommand\cdmdiaeresisb{^^^^0324}
\newcommand\cdmringb{^^^^0325}
\newcommand\cdmcommab{^^^^0326}
\newcommand\cdmcedilla{^^^^0327}
\newcommand\cdmogonek{^^^^0328}
\newcommand\cdmvlb{^^^^0329}
\newcommand\cdmbridgeb{^^^^032a}
\newcommand\cdminvdarchb{^^^^032b}
\newcommand\cdmcaronb{^^^^032c}
\newcommand\cdmcircumb{^^^^032d}
\newcommand\cdmbreveb{^^^^032e}
\newcommand\cdminvbreveb{^^^^032f}
\newcommand\cdmtildeb{^^^^0330}
\newcommand\cdmmacronb{^^^^0331}
\newcommand\cdmlowl{^^^^0332}
\newcommand\cdmdlowl{^^^^0333}
\newcommand\cdmtildeo{^^^^0334}
\newcommand\cdmshortstrokeo{^^^^0335}
\newcommand\cdmlongstrokeo{^^^^0336}
\newcommand\cdmshortsoliduso{^^^^0337}
\newcommand\cdmlongsoliduso{^^^^0338}
\newcommand\cdmrighthalfringb{^^^^0339}
\newcommand\cdminvbridgeb{^^^^033a}
\newcommand\cdmsquareb{^^^^033b}
\newcommand\cdmseagullb{^^^^033c}
\newcommand\cdmx{^^^^033d}
\newcommand\cdmvtilde{^^^^033e}
\newcommand\cdmdoverl{^^^^033f}
\newcommand\cdmgravetonemark{^^^^0340}
\newcommand\cdmacutetonemark{^^^^0341}
\newcommand\cdmgreekperispomeni{^^^^0342}
\newcommand\cdmgreekkoronis{^^^^0343}
\newcommand\cdmgreekdialytikatonos{^^^^0344}
\newcommand\cdmgreekypogegrammeni{^^^^0345}
\newcommand\cdmbridge{^^^^0346}
\newcommand\cdmequalssignb{^^^^0347}
\newcommand\cdmdvlb{^^^^0348}
\newcommand\cdmleftangleb{^^^^0349}
\newcommand\cdmnottilde{^^^^034a}
\newcommand\cdmhomothetic{^^^^034b}
\newcommand\cdmalmostequalto{^^^^034c}
\newcommand\cdmleftrightab{^^^^034d}
\newcommand\cdmupwardsab{^^^^034e}
\newcommand\cdmgraphemejoiner{^^^^034f}
\newcommand\cdmrighta{^^^^0350}
\newcommand\cdmlefthalfring{^^^^0351}
\newcommand\cdmfermata{^^^^0352}
\newcommand\cdmxb{^^^^0353}
\newcommand\cdmleftab{^^^^0354}
\newcommand\cdmrightab{^^^^0355}
\newcommand\cdmrightaupab{^^^^0356}
\newcommand\cdmrighthalfring{^^^^0357}
\newcommand\cdmdotright{^^^^0358}
\newcommand\cdmasteriskb{^^^^0359}
\newcommand\cdmdringb{^^^^035a}
\newcommand\cdmzigzag{^^^^035b}
\newcommand\cdmdbreveb{^^^^035c}
\newcommand\cdmdbreve{^^^^035d}
\newcommand\cdmdmacron{^^^^035e}
\newcommand\cdmdmacronb{^^^^035f}
\newcommand\cdmdtilde{^^^^0360}
\newcommand\cdmdinvbreve{^^^^0361}
\newcommand\cdmdrightwardsab{^^^^0362}
\newcommand\cdmlettera{^^^^0363}
\newcommand\cdmlettere{^^^^0364}
\newcommand\cdmletteri{^^^^0365}
\newcommand\cdmlettero{^^^^0366}
\newcommand\cdmletteru{^^^^0367}
\newcommand\cdmletterc{^^^^0368}
\newcommand\cdmletterd{^^^^0369}
\newcommand\cdmletterh{^^^^036a}
\newcommand\cdmletterm{^^^^036b}
\newcommand\cdmletterr{^^^^036c}
\newcommand\cdmlettert{^^^^036d}
\newcommand\cdmletterv{^^^^036e}
\newcommand\cdmletterx{^^^^036f}



%-----   List of Unicode codepoints
\newcommand\cdmshowplainlistuc{%
\noindent U+0300  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ò}\par
\noindent U+0301  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ó}\par
\noindent U+0302  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ô}\par
\noindent U+0303  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat õ}\par
\noindent U+0304  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ō}\par
\noindent U+0305  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̅}\par
\noindent U+0306  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ŏ}\par
\noindent U+0307  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ȯ}\par
\noindent U+0308  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ö}\par
\noindent U+0309  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ỏ}\par
\noindent U+030A  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̊}\par
\noindent U+030B  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ő}\par
\noindent U+030C  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ǒ}\par
\noindent U+030D  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̍}\par
\noindent U+030E  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̎}\par
\noindent U+030F  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ȍ}\par
\noindent U+0310  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̐}\par
\noindent U+0311  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ȏ}\par
\noindent U+0312  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̒}\par
\noindent U+0313  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̓}\par
\noindent U+0314  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̔}\par
\noindent U+0315  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̕}\par
\noindent U+0316  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̖}\par
\noindent U+0317  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̗}\par
\noindent U+0318  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̘}\par
\noindent U+0319  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̙}\par
\noindent U+031A  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̚}\par
\noindent U+031B  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ơ}\par
\noindent U+031C  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̜}\par
\noindent U+031D  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̝}\par
\noindent U+031E  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̞}\par
\noindent U+031F  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̟}\par
\noindent U+0320  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̠}\par
\noindent U+0321  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̡}\par
\noindent U+0322  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̢}\par
\noindent U+0323  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ọ}\par
\noindent U+0324  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̤}\par
\noindent U+0325  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̥}\par
\noindent U+0326  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̦}\par
\noindent U+0327  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̧}\par
\noindent U+0328  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ǫ}\par
\noindent U+0329  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̩}\par
\noindent U+032A  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̪}\par
\noindent U+032B  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̫}\par
\noindent U+032C  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̬}\par
\noindent U+032D  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̭}\par
\noindent U+032E  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̮}\par
\noindent U+032F  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̯}\par
\noindent U+0330  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̰}\par
\noindent U+0331  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̱}\par
\noindent U+0332  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̲}\par
\noindent U+0333  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̳}\par
\noindent U+0334  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̴}\par
\noindent U+0335  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̵}\par
\noindent U+0336  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̶}\par
\noindent U+0337  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̷}\par
\noindent U+0338  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̸}\par
\noindent U+0339  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̹}\par
\noindent U+033A  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̺}\par
\noindent U+033B  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̻}\par
\noindent U+033C  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̼}\par
\noindent U+033D  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̽}\par
\noindent U+033E  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̾}\par
\noindent U+033F  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̿}\par
\noindent U+0340  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ò}\par
\noindent U+0341  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ó}\par
\noindent U+0342  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͂}\par
\noindent U+0343  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̓}\par
\noindent U+0344  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ö́}\par
\noindent U+0345  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͅ}\par
\noindent U+0346  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͆}\par
\noindent U+0347  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͇}\par
\noindent U+0348  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͈}\par
\noindent U+0349  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͉}\par
\noindent U+034A  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͊}\par
\noindent U+034B  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͋}\par
\noindent U+034C  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͌}\par
\noindent U+034D  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͍}\par
\noindent U+034E  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͎}\par
\noindent U+034F  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͏}\par
\noindent U+0350  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͐}\par
\noindent U+0351  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͑}\par
\noindent U+0352  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͒}\par
\noindent U+0353  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͓}\par
\noindent U+0354  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͔}\par
\noindent U+0355  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͕}\par
\noindent U+0356  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͖}\par
\noindent U+0357  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͗}\par
\noindent U+0358  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͘}\par
\noindent U+0359  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͙}\par
\noindent U+035A  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͚}\par
\noindent U+035B  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͛}\par
\noindent U+035C  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͜}\par
\noindent U+035D  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͝}\par
\noindent U+035E  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͞}\par
\noindent U+035F  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͟}\par
\noindent U+0360  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͠}\par
\noindent U+0361  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͡}\par
\noindent U+0362  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͢}\par
\noindent U+0363  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͣ}\par
\noindent U+0364  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͤ}\par
\noindent U+0365  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͥ}\par
\noindent U+0366  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͦ}\par
\noindent U+0367  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͧ}\par
\noindent U+0368  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͨ}\par
\noindent U+0369  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͩ}\par
\noindent U+036A  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͪ}\par
\noindent U+036B  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͫ}\par
\noindent U+036C  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͬ}\par
\noindent U+036D  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͭ}\par
\noindent U+036E  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͮ}\par
\noindent U+036F  $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͯ}\par
}
%-----   List of Unicode names
\newcommand\cdmshowplainlistun{%
\noindent graveaccent $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ò}\par
\noindent acuteaccent $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ó}\par
\noindent circumflexaccent $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ô}\par
\noindent tilde $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat õ}\par
\noindent macron $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ō}\par
\noindent overline $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̅}\par
\noindent breve $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ŏ}\par
\noindent dotabove $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ȯ}\par
\noindent diaeresis $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ö}\par
\noindent hookabove $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ỏ}\par
\noindent ringabove $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̊}\par
\noindent doubleacuteaccent $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ő}\par
\noindent caron $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ǒ}\par
\noindent verticallineabove $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̍}\par
\noindent doubleverticallineabove $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̎}\par
\noindent doublegraveaccent $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ȍ}\par
\noindent candrabindu $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̐}\par
\noindent invertedbreve $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ȏ}\par
\noindent turnedcommaabove $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̒}\par
\noindent commaabove $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̓}\par
\noindent reversedcommaabove $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̔}\par
\noindent commaaboveright $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̕}\par
\noindent graveaccentbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̖}\par
\noindent acuteaccentbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̗}\par
\noindent lefttackbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̘}\par
\noindent righttackbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̙}\par
\noindent leftangleabove $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̚}\par
\noindent horn $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ơ}\par
\noindent lefthalfringbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̜}\par
\noindent uptackbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̝}\par
\noindent downtackbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̞}\par
\noindent plussignbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̟}\par
\noindent minussignbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̠}\par
\noindent palatalizedhookbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̡}\par
\noindent retroflexhookbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̢}\par
\noindent dotbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ọ}\par
\noindent diaeresisbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̤}\par
\noindent ringbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̥}\par
\noindent commabelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̦}\par
\noindent cedilla $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̧}\par
\noindent ogonek $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ǫ}\par
\noindent verticallinebelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̩}\par
\noindent bridgebelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̪}\par
\noindent inverteddoublearchbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̫}\par
\noindent caronbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̬}\par
\noindent circumflexaccentbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̭}\par
\noindent brevebelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̮}\par
\noindent invertedbrevebelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̯}\par
\noindent tildebelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̰}\par
\noindent macronbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̱}\par
\noindent lowline $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̲}\par
\noindent doublelowline $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̳}\par
\noindent tildeoverlay $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̴}\par
\noindent shortstrokeoverlay $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̵}\par
\noindent longstrokeoverlay $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̶}\par
\noindent shortsolidusoverlay $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̷}\par
\noindent longsolidusoverlay $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̸}\par
\noindent righthalfringbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̹}\par
\noindent invertedbridgebelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̺}\par
\noindent squarebelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̻}\par
\noindent seagullbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̼}\par
\noindent xabove $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̽}\par
\noindent verticaltilde $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̾}\par
\noindent doubleoverline $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̿}\par
\noindent gravetonemark $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ò}\par
\noindent acutetonemark $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ó}\par
\noindent greekperispomeni $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͂}\par
\noindent greekkoronis $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̓}\par
\noindent greekdialytikatonos $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ö́}\par
\noindent greekypogegrammeni $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͅ}\par
\noindent bridgeabove $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͆}\par
\noindent equalssignbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͇}\par
\noindent doubleverticallinebelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͈}\par
\noindent leftanglebelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͉}\par
\noindent nottildeabove $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͊}\par
\noindent homotheticabove $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͋}\par
\noindent almostequaltoabove $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͌}\par
\noindent leftrightarrowbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͍}\par
\noindent upwardsarrowbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͎}\par
\noindent graphemejoiner $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͏}\par
\noindent rightarrowheadabove $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͐}\par
\noindent lefthalfringabove $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͑}\par
\noindent fermata $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͒}\par
\noindent xbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͓}\par
\noindent leftarrowheadbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͔}\par
\noindent rightarrowheadbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͕}\par
\noindent rightarrowheadanduparrowheadbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͖}\par
\noindent righthalfringabove $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͗}\par
\noindent dotaboveright $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͘}\par
\noindent asteriskbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͙}\par
\noindent doubleringbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͚}\par
\noindent zigzagabove $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͛}\par
\noindent doublebrevebelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͜}\par
\noindent doublebreve $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͝}\par
\noindent doublemacron $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͞}\par
\noindent doublemacronbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͟}\par
\noindent doubletilde $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͠}\par
\noindent doubleinvertedbreve $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͡}\par
\noindent doublerightwardsarrowbelow $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͢}\par
\noindent latinsmalllettera $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͣ}\par
\noindent latinsmalllettere $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͤ}\par
\noindent latinsmallletteri $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͥ}\par
\noindent latinsmalllettero $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͦ}\par
\noindent latinsmallletteru $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͧ}\par
\noindent latinsmallletterc $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͨ}\par
\noindent latinsmallletterd $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͩ}\par
\noindent latinsmallletterh $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͪ}\par
\noindent latinsmallletterm $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͫ}\par
\noindent latinsmallletterr $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͬ}\par
\noindent latinsmalllettert $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͭ}\par
\noindent latinsmallletterv $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͮ}\par
\noindent latinsmallletterx $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͯ}\par
}

%-----   List of Typing shortcuts
\newcommand\cdmshowplainlistts{%
\noindent cdmgrave $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ò}\par
\noindent cdmacute $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ó}\par
\noindent cdmcircum $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ô}\par
\noindent cdmtilde $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat õ}\par
\noindent cdmmacron $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ō}\par
\noindent cdmoverl $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̅}\par
\noindent cdmbreve $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ŏ}\par
\noindent cdmdot $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ȯ}\par
\noindent cdmdiaeresis $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ö}\par
\noindent cdmhook $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ỏ}\par
\noindent cdmring $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̊}\par
\noindent cdmdacute $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ő}\par
\noindent cdmcaron $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ǒ}\par
\noindent cdmvl $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̍}\par
\noindent cdmdvl $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̎}\par
\noindent cdmdgrave $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ȍ}\par
\noindent cdmcrabindu $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̐}\par
\noindent cdminvbreve $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ȏ}\par
\noindent cdmtcomma $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̒}\par
\noindent cdmcomma $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̓}\par
\noindent cdmrevcomma $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̔}\par
\noindent cdmcommaright $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̕}\par
\noindent cdmgraveb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̖}\par
\noindent cdmacuteb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̗}\par
\noindent cdmlefttackb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̘}\par
\noindent cdmrighttackb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̙}\par
\noindent cdmleftangle $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̚}\par
\noindent cdmhorn $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ơ}\par
\noindent cdmlefthalfringb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̜}\par
\noindent cdmuptackb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̝}\par
\noindent cdmdowntackb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̞}\par
\noindent cdmplussignb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̟}\par
\noindent cdmminussignb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̠}\par
\noindent cdmpalatalizedhookb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̡}\par
\noindent cdmretroflexhookb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̢}\par
\noindent cdmdotb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ọ}\par
\noindent cdmdiaeresisb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̤}\par
\noindent cdmringb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̥}\par
\noindent cdmcommab $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̦}\par
\noindent cdmcedilla $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̧}\par
\noindent cdmogonek $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ǫ}\par
\noindent cdmvlb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̩}\par
\noindent cdmbridgeb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̪}\par
\noindent cdminvdarchb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̫}\par
\noindent cdmcaronb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̬}\par
\noindent cdmcircumb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̭}\par
\noindent cdmbreveb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̮}\par
\noindent cdminvbreveb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̯}\par
\noindent cdmtildeb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̰}\par
\noindent cdmmacronb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̱}\par
\noindent cdmlowl $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̲}\par
\noindent cdmdlowl $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̳}\par
\noindent cdmtildeo $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̴}\par
\noindent cdmshortstrokeo $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̵}\par
\noindent cdmlongstrokeo $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̶}\par
\noindent cdmshortsoliduso $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̷}\par
\noindent cdmlongsoliduso $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̸}\par
\noindent cdmrighthalfringb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̹}\par
\noindent cdminvbridgeb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̺}\par
\noindent cdmsquareb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̻}\par
\noindent cdmseagullb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̼}\par
\noindent cdmx $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̽}\par
\noindent cdmvtilde $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̾}\par
\noindent cdmdoverl $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̿}\par
\noindent cdmgravetonemark $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ò}\par
\noindent cdmacutetonemark $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ó}\par
\noindent cdmgreekperispomeni $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͂}\par
\noindent cdmgreekkoronis $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o̓}\par
\noindent cdmgreekdialytikatonos $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat ö́}\par
\noindent cdmgreekypogegrammeni $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͅ}\par
\noindent cdmbridge $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͆}\par
\noindent cdmequalssignb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͇}\par
\noindent cdmdvlb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͈}\par
\noindent cdmleftangleb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͉}\par
\noindent cdmnottilde $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͊}\par
\noindent cdmhomothetic $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͋}\par
\noindent cdmalmostequalto $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͌}\par
\noindent cdmleftrightab $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͍}\par
\noindent cdmupwardsab $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͎}\par
\noindent cdmgraphemejoiner $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͏}\par
\noindent cdmrighta $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͐}\par
\noindent cdmlefthalfring $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͑}\par
\noindent cdmfermata $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͒}\par
\noindent cdmxb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͓}\par
\noindent cdmleftab $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͔}\par
\noindent cdmrightab $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͕}\par
\noindent cdmrightaupab $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͖}\par
\noindent cdmrighthalfring $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͗}\par
\noindent cdmdotright $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͘}\par
\noindent cdmasteriskb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͙}\par
\noindent cdmdringb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͚}\par
\noindent cdmzigzag $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͛}\par
\noindent cdmdbreveb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͜}\par
\noindent cdmdbreve $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͝}\par
\noindent cdmdmacron $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͞}\par
\noindent cdmdmacronb $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͟}\par
\noindent cdmdtilde $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͠}\par
\noindent cdmdinvbreve $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͡}\par
\noindent cdmdrightwardsab $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat o͢}\par
\noindent cdmlettera $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͣ}\par
\noindent cdmlettere $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͤ}\par
\noindent cdmletteri $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͥ}\par
\noindent cdmlettero $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͦ}\par
\noindent cdmletteru $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͧ}\par
\noindent cdmletterc $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͨ}\par
\noindent cdmletterd $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͩ}\par
\noindent cdmletterh $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͪ}\par
\noindent cdmletterm $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͫ}\par
\noindent cdmletterr $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͬ}\par
\noindent cdmlettert $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͭ}\par
\noindent cdmletterv $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͮ}\par
\noindent cdmletterx $\mapsto$ {\cdmformat oͯ}\par
}
\newcommand\testcdm[1]{%
CDM test using [#1]:\par
\begin{quotation}
#1\cdmgrave\ 
#1\cdmacute\ 
#1\cdmcircum\ 
#1\cdmtilde\ 
#1\cdmmacron\ 
#1\cdmoverl\ 
#1\cdmbreve\ 
#1\cdmdot\ 
\textcolor{red}{#1\cdmdiaeresis}\ 
#1\cdmhook\ 
#1\cdmring\ 
#1\cdmdacute\ 
#1\cdmcaron\ 
#1\cdmvl\ 
#1\cdmdvl\ 
#1\cdmdgrave\ 
#1\cdmcrabindu\ 
#1\cdminvbreve\ 
#1\cdmtcomma\ 
#1\cdmcomma\ 
#1\cdmrevcomma\ 
#1\cdmcommaright\ 
#1\cdmgraveb\ 
#1\cdmacuteb\ 
#1\cdmlefttackb\ 
#1\cdmrighttackb\ 
#1\cdmleftangle\ 
#1\cdmhorn\ 
#1\cdmlefthalfringb\ 
#1\cdmuptackb\ 
#1\cdmdowntackb\ 
#1\cdmplussignb\ 
#1\cdmminussignb\ 
#1\cdmpalatalizedhookb\ 
#1\cdmretroflexhookb\ 
#1\cdmdotb\ 
#1\cdmdiaeresisb\ 
#1\cdmringb\ 
#1\cdmcommab\ 
#1\cdmcedilla\ 
#1\cdmogonek\ 
#1\cdmvlb\ 
#1\cdmbridgeb\ 
#1\cdminvdarchb\ 
#1\cdmcaronb\ 
#1\cdmcircumb\ 
#1\cdmbreveb\ 
#1\cdminvbreveb\ 
#1\cdmtildeb\ 
#1\cdmmacronb\ 
#1\cdmlowl\ 
#1\cdmdlowl\ 
#1\cdmtildeo\ 
#1\cdmshortstrokeo\ 
#1\cdmlongstrokeo\ 
#1\cdmshortsoliduso\ 
#1\cdmlongsoliduso\ 
#1\cdmrighthalfringb\ 
#1\cdminvbridgeb\ 
#1\cdmsquareb\ 
#1\cdmseagullb\ 
#1\cdmx\ 
#1\cdmvtilde\ 
#1\cdmdoverl\ 
#1\cdmgravetonemark\ 
#1\cdmacutetonemark\ 
#1\cdmgreekperispomeni\ 
#1\cdmgreekkoronis\ 
#1\cdmgreekdialytikatonos\ 
#1\cdmgreekypogegrammeni\ 
#1\cdmbridge\ 
#1\cdmequalssignb\ 
#1\cdmdvlb\ 
#1\cdmleftangleb\ 
#1\cdmnottilde\ 
#1\cdmhomothetic\ 
#1\cdmalmostequalto\ 
#1\cdmleftrightab\ 
#1\cdmupwardsab\ 
#1\cdmgraphemejoiner\ 
#1\cdmrighta\ 
#1\cdmlefthalfring\ 
#1\cdmfermata\ 
#1\cdmxb\ 
#1\cdmleftab\ 
#1\cdmrightab\ 
#1\cdmrightaupab\ 
#1\cdmrighthalfring\ 
#1\cdmdotright\ 
#1\cdmasteriskb\ 
#1\cdmdringb\ 
#1\cdmzigzag\ 
#1\cdmdbreveb\ 
#1\cdmdbreve\ 
#1\cdmdmacron\ 
#1\cdmdmacronb\ 
#1\cdmdtilde\ 
#1\cdmdinvbreve\ 
#1\cdmdrightwardsab\ 
#1\cdmlettera\ 
#1\cdmlettere\ 
#1\cdmletteri\ 
#1\cdmlettero\ 
#1\cdmletteru\ 
#1\cdmletterc\ 
#1\cdmletterd\ 
#1\cdmletterh\ 
#1\cdmletterm\ 
#1\cdmletterr\ 
#1\cdmlettert\ 
#1\cdmletterv\ 
#1\cdmletterx\ 
\end{quotation}
}
%^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

\begin{document}

{

\noindent θ + a combining diacritical mark

\noindent \verb|θ^^^^0308| $\mapsto$ θ^^^^0308

\bigskip
It would be handy to have a set of commands with (relatively) short-names to access these combining diacritical marks rather than having to type in the codepoints or the mark directly, such that, for example, \colorbox{blue!5}{\color{blue}\ttfamily a\textbackslash cdmacute} produces {\color{blue}a\cdmacute}, \colorbox{blue!5}{\color{blue}\ttfamily a\textbackslash cdmdotb} produces {\color{blue}a\cdmdotb}, and so on.




\testcdm{o}



\section{Combining Diacritical Marks}
\subsection{List of Unicode codepoints}
\begin{multicols}{4}\noindent
\cdmtag
\cdmshowplainlistuc
\eolist
\end{multicols}

\subsection{List of Unicode names}
\begin{multicols}{2}\noindent
\cdmtag
\cdmshowplainlistun
\eolist
\end{multicols}

\subsection{List of Typing Shortcuts}
\begin{multicols}{3}\noindent
\cdmtag
\cdmshowplainlistts
\eolist
\end{multicols}

\bigskip
The naming convention for the shortcuts is based on the Unicode name, with some abbreviating:

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\bfseries String & \bfseries Replaced with \\ 
\hline
above &  \\ 
accent &  \\ 
and &  \\ 
arrow & a \\ 
below & b \\ 
circumflex & circum \\ 
combining & cdm \\ 
double & d \\ 
head &  \\ 
inverted & inv \\ 
latin small &  \\ 
line & l \\ 
overlay & o \\ 
reversed & rev \\ 
turned & t \\ 
vertical & v \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}



\end{document}

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595697/greek-letter-with-two-dots-over-in-text-mode
```